# ssh-add git public key not saved

Tags: linux, macos

I have to set each time that I reboot the system (macos):

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bb
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

It doesn't get saved, why? If I don't do that I get:

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: This should help you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250572

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can make a file by name 'config' in file .ssh, and write this command to synchrony your ssh:

```
sudo touch config
```

and the contents of the folder are:

```
# bitbucket.org
Host git@bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bb
```

Comment: useful, good job